# Спарсить с сайта наличие товара

Tags: парсер, синтаксический-анализ, php, javascript

Добрый день друзья. Хочу спарсить с сайта икеа наличие товара. По такому адресу http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/catalog/availability/10131699/ , но когда начинаю брать данные функцией file_get_html() выводит все кроме того, что мне нужно. Как я понял для того чтобы выводилось наличие товара, нужно выбрать магазин, в котором нужно провести проверку(Справа) И он выбирается средствами JS. Как спарсить наличие например с магазина Белая дача? Пожалуйста, подскажите, люди добрые.

Comment: http://www.ikea.com/ru/ru/iows/catalog/availability/10131699

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Если не трудно поясните, это xml файл правильно? И откуда его брать чтобы я знал на будущее

Comment: я его взял из консоли браузера, да это видимо xml.

Comment: Подскажите откуда именно из консоли, чтобы знать. Я вот смотрю исходный код страницы не понимаю откуда вы взяли ссылку на xml файл

Comment: в хроме например - devtools -> вкладка network, там список того куда оно обращалось.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!